# this.el.object3D.position.set(0,0,0) doesn't work if without breakpoint in debugger

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I append a element(door) to the element of Vive(blue box) controller.

After appending I want to set the position of door as '0 0 0' with code "this.el.object3D.position.set(0,0,0)", to attach the door to the blue box.

But it doesn't work, if no breakpoint in debbuger of browser uesed.

When I set breakpoint and go through it, the result is correct.

Code with demo in Glitch: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/aedfdc5a-698b-4e6c-96c3-4dddfce0a6eb

Maybe someone knows the reason?

Thanks for any help.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the child element is not fully done appending itself when you try to change the position.

You can easily check it by making a timer, which goes after `append()` and changes the position.

---

You can use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), which will fire an event, when a child is attached.
Then you can make the changes:

```
var viveController, door
// Observer config -> what am i going to react upon
var observerOptions = {    
  childList: true,
}
// create the observer - it takes a callback as an argument
// no need to filter what event was caught, just move the damn door
var observer = new MutationObserver((e)=>{
     door.setAttribute("position", "0, 0, 0")
});

observer.observe(viveController, observerOptions);
viveController.appendChild(door)
```

check it out working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/topk9ugc/26/).

Comment: you are right, that is really the reason. And MutationObserver works well. Thank you very much!

Comment: glad i could help, can't believe i've never stumbled upon this before :)

Comment: How did you find the reason. Actually I search the reason for a long time.

Comment: I've manipulated child entities before, so i thought its either a bug, or it's because `append` and `setAttribute` are called immidiately one after another. Making a minimal fiddle made it easier, as there are less variables in the equation :)

Comment: ADMIRE you!  : )